# I am sure Ray knows the answer . (Rewrite using "must be or could (may, might)be or can't be")

Tags: grammar

I learnt in this English lesson that this sentence shows certainty so we should use "must be" but I can not find the rule where we use "must be" + verb .
How should the sentence be like?

Comment: **ᴍᴏᴅᴇʀᴀᴛᴏʀ ɴᴏᴛᴇ:** Please do not answer in comments. Write an answer. It can even be an 
incomplete germ of an answer, but please put it in the right place. The
Q&A system cannot cope with answers in comments, and will not mark the question as
answered if you do that. Answering in comments circumvents the very
facilities that allow our Q&A community to police itself and maintain site
quality. If the question requires closing, then please vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'must' the sentence can be

> Ray must know the answer.

Using 'must be' works in a dialect that uses the [**present continuous tense**](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/present-continuous) in this way

> Ray must be knowing the answer.

This phrasing isn't an idiomatic use of the tense in American or British English, although it might be seen in Indian English.

Changing the meaning of the original sentence slightly, I suggest

> Ray must be someone who knows the answer.

Comment: The question put to OP was almost certainly poorly framed (assuming the facts are as reported).

Answer (score 0):

You are really asking about the use of "must" in English.  This word means either the obligation to do something, or certainty about something.  "You MUST finish your work before 5pm."  That does not mean we are certain you will do so, just that you are required to do so.  You might fail.

In comparison, "He MUST be sad now that his pet died" means we are certain that sadness would be felt in this situation, not that there is any OBLIGATION to feel that way.